# Writing a program for days in months

Tags: python, if-statement

So I'm trying to write a code where whatever number of the month it is, it returns me the number of days there are in this month. Here is the code I have written at the moment. I got some of the months right but the rest aren't. Can someone point out what I did wrong with the coding?

```
def get_days_in_month (month):
    if (month == 2):
        return 28
    elif (month == 4 + 6 + 9 + 11):
        return 30
    elif (month == 1 + 3 + 5 + 7 + 8 + 10 +12):
        return 31
    else:
        return 31
```

Comment: Why are you adding the numbers here: `month == 4 + 6 + 9 + 11`?

Comment: i added them so i can include those months in since they have the same amount of days in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding the numbers `4`, `6`, `9`, `11`. You can instead test to see if `month` equals one of those by using the [`in` keyword](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_keyword_in.asp) and a [`list`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp):

```
def get_days_in_month(month):

    if (month == 2):
        return 28
    elif (month in [4, 6, 9, 11]):
        return 30
    else:
        return 31
```

Answer (score 3):

Better idea:

Use python's built in calculator. Use monthrange and pass in (int) of year and month

> monthrange(year,month): Returns weekday of first day of the month and number of days in month,
>   for the specified year and month

```
from calendar import monthrange

def get_days_in_month (year,month):
    month_data= monthrange(year, month)
    # If you only want DAYS, use month_data[1] 
get_days_in_month(2018,1)
```